# How can I make Vimscript check if the current line has a comment?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, comments

I want to make a Python `ftplugin` (but other filetypes will also have this option) where, if the previous line has a comment that starts with `#`, the next line can be commented via `<Shift><CR>`, an insert-mode mapping (`inoremap`). How can I code Vimscript so that it checks whether the current line is commented, and subsequently allows the `inoremap` to make a new line commented?

And please don't recommend a third-party plugin like `NERD Commenter` (which, btw, I respect very much), I want something as close to vanilla-Vim as possible for this.

Comment: I don't get the goal of this mapping. If you want to be able to use `<CR>` to add a line with no comment and `<Shift-CR>` to add a comment, why do you need it to be conditional on whether the current line has a comment? If you don't want a comment added when you're not currently on a commented line, why would you pressing `<Shift-CR>` in that case? Am I misunderstanding the behaviour of the mapping you want to create?

Comment: Oh...shoot you're right. I didn't think of that before lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the current line is commented, you can use

```
:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("$")-1, 1)), "name")
```

This checks, if the current line ends with a comment syntax item.

You can then do something like this:

```
inoremap <expr><silent> <f6> synIDattr(synID(line('.')-1, strlen(getline(line('.')-1)), 1),'name')=~?'comment'?'#':' '
```

this maps the <kbd>F6</kbd> key to check if the syntax group from the end of the previous line matches `comment` and if so returns the comment character `#`, else it will simply return a <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Checking the syntax instead of the content is super clever!

Comment: One could probably even lean on `'commentstring'` (which i think tpope’s commentary does).

Comment: Checking the syntax was much more helpful than other things I've tried! Thanks for the help.